# When is zswap used?

Tags: linux, zswap

I would like to reduce the wear of my SSD.

I'm trying to understand the mechanics of zswap:

Is zswap only used after the uncompresed swap is full?

If no, what is the allocation policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/zswap.txt) says:

> Zswap evicts pages from compressed cache on an LRU basis to the backing swap
>   device when the compressed pool reaches its size limit.  This requirement had
>   been identified in prior community discussions.

This means that zswap (which is held in RAM) is used *before* swap, and when full, the oldest pages will be moved to swap to make space for new pages waiting to be written to zswap.

[Temporal locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference#Types_of_locality) says that more recently used pages are more likely to be used again.